# Carbon fibre laser beam dump material?

Tags: material-science, laser

A few years ago I came across a material used as a high power laser beam dump. It was made from carbon fibre which looked like a mat made of high density bristles ie all the fibres on the top of the mat were vertical. It performed exceptionally well, re-radiating rather than conducting most of the heat away. Anyway, the questions: Are there similar materials in such configurations? And what is that kind of weave called?

Comment: Interesting, I've never come across such a material.  At what wavelength did it operate?

Comment: It was used to intercept a 1200W continuous CO2 laser at 10.6u. I only saw it as an experiment but after a minute or so in the beam, glowing white hot, it appeared undamaged. This was 20 years ago. Never seen anything like it since.

Comment: 1200W!?  It certainly wasn't standard carbon fiber which is encased in a plastic resin.  We've used [Silicon Carbide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_carbide) for beam dumps at ~250 W CW Nd:YAG with an aluminum radiative heat sink attached to the back.

Comment: It was some kind of free standing bunched fibres, very dense and stacked like a deep pile carpet. The target area was about a square centimetre. Only about 3cm deep.

Comment: I thought razor blades were a useful cheap beam dump?

Comment: They certainly are, but you wouldn't want to use them above ~1 W.

Answer (score 2):

I think the material you're thinking of is called Vel-Black and is made by a company called Energy Science Laboratories.  As I recall from a NASA Tech Briefs article, it's made from carbon nanotubes and is on a fabric substrate.  Good for beam dumps but be careful about exceeding the damage threshold because breathing in the carbon material that is ablated off is bad for your health.